# Applying partial fraction decomposition when evaluating a contour integral

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, partial-fractions

Take for example the integral in (1) where $\gamma$ is the anticlockwise path around the top half of the circle $|z|=r$

According to Wolfram, $$\int \frac{1}{z+w}dz=\operatorname{Log}\left(z+w\right)+C$$

Let $\gamma(t)=re^{it}$

Then

$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{a^{2}+z^{2}}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{γ'\left(t\right)dt}{a^{2}+\left(γ\left(t\right)\right)^{2}}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{ire^{it}dt}{a^{2}+r^{2}e^{2it}}=i\int_{r}^{-r}\frac{u\frac{du}{iu}}{a^{2}+u^{2}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{a}\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-r}{a}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{a}\right)\right)$$ $\tag1$

But

$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{a^{2}+z^{2}}=\int_{\gamma} \frac{\frac{i}{2a}}{z+ai}-\frac{\frac{i}{2a}}{z-ai}dz=\int_{0}^{\pi}(\frac{\frac{i}{2a}}{γ\left(t\right)+ai}-\frac{\frac{i}{2a}}{γ\left(t\right)-ai})γ'\left(t\right)dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\frac{re^{it}}{re^{it}-ai}-\frac{re^{it}}{re^{it}+ai}\right)dt=\frac{1}{2a}\int_{r}^{-r}\left(\frac{u\frac{du}{iu}}{u-ai}\right)-\frac{1}{2a}\int_{r}^{-r}\left(\frac{u\frac{du}{iu}}{u+ai}\right)$$
$$=\frac{i}{2a}\left(\operatorname{Log}\left(r-ai\right)+\operatorname{Log}\left(-r+ai\right)-\operatorname{Log}\left(r+ai\right)-\operatorname{Log}\left(-r-ai\right)\right)$$ $\tag2$

Which then implies that (1) and (2) are equal, but according to [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=arctan%5C%2840%29-r%5C%2841%29-arctan%5C%2840%29r%5C%2841%29-%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29i%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%292%5C%28125%29%5Cleft%5C%2840%29%5Cln%5Cleft%5C%2840%29r-i%5Cright%5C%2841%29%2B%5Cln%5Cleft%5C%2840%29-r%2Bi%5Cright%5C%2841%29-%5Cln%5Cleft%5C%2840%29r%2Bi%5Cright%5C%2841%29-%5Cln%5Cleft%5C%2840%29-r-i%5Cright%5C%2841%29%5Cright%5C%2841%29) they are not.

All integration methods should converge on the same result, right? But something seems to go wrong when verifying that using partial fractions will yield the same result yielded by another method.

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Im%5C%2840%29arctan%5C%2840%29-r%5C%2841%29-arctan%5C%2840%29r%5C%2841%29-%5Cfrac%5C%28123%29i%5C%28125%29%5C%28123%292%5C%28125%29%5Cleft%5C%2840%29%5Clog%5Cleft%5C%2840%29r-i%5Cright%5C%2841%29%2B%5Clog%5Cleft%5C%2840%29-r%2Bi%5Cright%5C%2841%29-%5Clog%5Cleft%5C%2840%29r%2Bi%5Cright%5C%2841%29-%5Clog%5Cleft%5C%2840%29-r-i%5Cright%5C%2841%29%5Cright%5C%2841%29) does say that the imaginary part of the difference is zero

###### Update

It can be verified that (1) and (2) are equal for the case where $a=1$

Thus, what I'm fairly sure is going on is that they are indeed equal but Wolfram simply doesn't choose to state that zero is an alternate form of the difference when $a=1$

The verification goes as follows:

Since $\operatorname{Arctan}(z)=\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Log}(\frac{i+z}{i-z})$, if $x$ is a positive real number then $\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Log}(\frac{i+x}{i-x})$

Therefore,

$$\tan^{-1}\left(-r\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(r\right)=_{?}\frac{i}{2}\left(Log\left(r-i\right)+Log\left(-r+i\right)-Log\left(r+i\right)-Log\left(-r-i\right)\right)$$

$$-2\tan^{-1}\left(r\right)=_{?}\frac{i}{2}Log\left(\frac{\left(r-i\right)^{2}}{\left(r+i\right)^{2}}\right)$$

$$-2\left(\frac{i}{2}Log\left(\frac{i+r}{i-r}\right)\right)=_{?}\frac{i}{2}Log\left(\frac{\left(r-i\right)^{2}}{\left(r+i\right)^{2}}\right)$$

$$2\left(\frac{i}{2}Log\left(\frac{i-r}{i+r}\right)\right)=_{?}\frac{i}{2}Log\left(\frac{\left(r-i\right)^{2}}{\left(r+i\right)^{2}}\right)$$

$$\frac{i}{2}Log\left(\frac{\left(i-r\right)^{2}}{\left(i+r\right)^{2}}\right)=_{yes}\frac{i}{2}Log\left(\frac{\left(r-i\right)^{2}}{\left(r+i\right)^{2}}\right)$$

It can be justified that $\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Log}(\frac{i+x}{i-x})$ by using partial fractions to evaluate the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and using $\int \frac{1}{z+w}dz=\operatorname{Log}\left(z+w\right)+C$

Comment: Where are the branches of the logarithm function, and where is Wolfram assuming the branch for each one?

Comment: I'm not privy to what convention Wolfram is using. Your guess is better than mine

Comment: The Wolfram link you provided seems to me to indicate that the two functions are equal...! (I assume the input is the difference of the two)

Comment: If it is using the same routines as Mathematica "$\texttt{Log[z]}$ has a branch cut discontinuity in the complex $z$ plane running from $-\infty$ to $0.$"

Comment: @GregMartin can you share how one can show that the difference is equal to zero for all $r$ in the domain?

Comment: The graph does seem to indicate it's zero but you'd figure that Wolfram would state that 0 is an alternative form if that were so